# onClick starting another activity

Tags: android

```
private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startService(new Intent(SimpleServiceController.this,
                SimpleUpdateService.class));
        startActivity(new Intent (this, AlarmManagerListening.class));
    }
};
```

Problem occur at startActivity execution. It doesnt allow me to start an activity. May I know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Use `SimpleServiceController.this` instead of `this` for `startActivity()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are facing is because of the use of **this** in `startActivity(new Intent (this, AlarmManagerListening.class));`. Since you are instantiating a new instance of OnClickListener **this** refers to the instance of the listener and not to your service which is required as a Context. By utilizing `SimpleServiceController.this` you specify that **this** refers to your controller which is a subclass of Context like required by the `new Intent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent (v.getContext(), SimpleService.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
```